# Minimum version of Visual Studio requirement for Windows Phone 8.1 application development

Tags: visual-studio

What is the minimum version of Visual Studio required for developing Windows Phone 8.1 application, can Visual Studio 2012 (Update 4) be used to develop the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629632.aspx), Windows Phone 8.1 development requires Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or newer, you can't use Visual Studio 2012. Note that although that page recommends installing the Express edition of Visual Studio if you don't have a paid one, it is better to install the Community edition (and of course, now you should go for VS 2015 instead of VS 2013).